# Why is my SVG document using a copy of itself in place of an image in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

I have an SVG document [here](http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/index.svg)

<strike>On firefox, everything works as expected</strike>. However, google chrome appears to think this line:

```
<image ... xlink:href="/textures/Cube top.png" />
```

references `http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/index.svg`,
not `http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/textures/Cube top.png`,
resulting in unexpected recursion.

Obviously, I'd much prefer it if it used the image I specify.

What is going on here?

---

**EDIT:** Filed bug [#68732](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68732) in Chrome. May still be doing something wrong though.

Comment: The SVG file that you link to does not have any `bmp` file in it. `curl --silent http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/index.svg | grep bmp #no output`. If it did, you should have URL-encoded the space in the name with `%20`.

Comment: I see, you renamed your images from 'bmp' to 'png'. I've updated your question accordingly. Further, your SVG [appears to be syntactically valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fminecraft-cube.comuv.com%2Findex.svg&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0).

Comment: @Phrogz: Yep, thought the problem might be the bitmap images. Obviously wasn't, but PNGs are more suited anyway.

Comment: @Phrogz: Curiouser and curiouser: Seems to be a consequence of the `<use>` element. [This document](http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/index-test-2.svg) should show four tiles in a grid. Clockwise: `<image>` tag, `<use>` of group containing `<image>` in `<defs>`, `<use>` of first tile `<image>`, `<use>` of `<image>` in `<defs>`. Only the first shows

Comment: @Eric I see four images in that document using Google Chrome v9.0 on Windows. (Although the result is different than in Safari; in Chrome all but the upper left are smaller than in Safari.) If you are using an older version, perhaps it's an old bug that just needs to be fixed.

Comment: Wut? It now displays them. It didn't use to. This makes no sense.

Comment: However, they should be the same size

Comment: Hang on, I know what's happening. We've got the self-reference issue again. That small square is a thumbnail of the entire document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem exists elsewhere. Here is a simplified version of your document that correctly shows the linked image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 48 84" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <g id="top-tile">
            <image width="1" height="1" x="-0.5" y="-0.5" class="face"
             xlink:href="http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/textures/Cube top.png" />
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g transform="scale(16)">
        <g transform="translate(1.5, 1.5)">
            <use xlink:href="#top-tile" />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

If I use absolute paths to your images and  remove the `clip-path` attributes I see your images in Safari and Chrome. If I put the `clip-path` back in I see all black fill in Safari, but what is presumably correct in Chrome. If you put in absolute paths (e.g. `xlink:href="http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/textures/Cube top.png"`) does it work for you in Chrome?

*Now that I see what you are trying to make, I wish I could give you +2 for making a fold-up Minecraft tile :)*

**Edit** Next Steps:

1. Remove the space from your file name.
2. Try using a relative path instead of absolute.
3. Now that we know better the core issue, Google for more answers (I haven't found any)
4. Pare it down to a trivial test case and [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) against Chrome.

**Edit 2**: As shown in the updated question, @Eric did [file a bug against Chrome](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68732). As shown in that bug report, newer versions of Chrome display the intended result. Further, a [slightly modified test case](http://phrogz.net/SVG/test_image_references.svg) using explicit pixel-based image height and width, and pixel-based SVG viewBox and dimensions works in all browsers tested.

Comment: Yes, absolute paths work. However, I'd really rather not throw absolute URLs around everywhere. I also tried adding `xml:base="http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/"` to my `svg` element, but that didn't work either. Thoughts?

Comment: Also, it's not just a _fold-up_ Minecraft tile. It's a **pop-up** minecraft tile

Comment: @Eric Even cooler! I've updated the answer with additional suggestions. :)

Comment: I guess I'll just use absolute URLs for now. Thanks for the tips.

Comment: What it _should_ look like [(absolute urls)](http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/index-absolute.svg)

Comment: As of Firefox 5, [your demo](http://phrogz.net/SVG/test_image_references.svg) no longer works.

Comment: Not interesting, irritating. [My SVG](http://minecraft-cube.comuv.com/cube) is broken again.

Comment: do you remember which version of FF you got it working in? I'm filing a bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675577), but I can't report a regression if I donn't remember which version it worked in. Thanks.